# How to avoid code duplication in MediatR request handlers?

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, cqrs, mediatr

I am playing around with CQRS and the MediatR library, trying to learn some of the best practices.
One problem I have is code duplication in Command/Query handlers. I would like to know what is the best way to share logic between handlers.

Example:
I have an abstract Entity class that defines an ID property. All entities inherit from that class.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    protected Entity(long id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then for every entity, I want to create a GetById query. One of those queries looks like so:

```
public class GetUserByIdQuery : IRequest<UserDto>
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, UserDto>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<User> repository;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public Handler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            repository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<User>();
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
        public async Task<UserDto> Handle(GetUserByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = await repository.FindAsync(request.UserId, null, cancellationToken);
            if (user is null)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException();
            }

            return mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that this class looks exactly the same for all the entities. Without CQRS I would probably have something like this:

```
public class EntityFinder<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : Entity
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> repository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public EntityFinder(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        repository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<TEntity>();
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    public async Task<TDto> GetByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var entity = await repository.FindAsync(id);
        if (entity is null)
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        return mapper.Map<TDto>(entity);
    }
}
```

I tried doing something similar with a generic query and handler but MediatR had trouble finding the handler (even when I tried registering it manually to the DI container).

What is the best way to avoid such duplication?

Comment: I have been diving into Mediatr lately as well, and one of the things I've been trying to adjust to is the feeling of having code duplication. Looking into some talks done by Jimmy Bogard (the library maintainer) it seems that he views this as a benefit to an extent because it means when a change is made to a command or query, only that one instance is changed, with no risk to the others. It also allows you to have different input and output DTOs for example. Looking forward to seeing what others with a bit more experience have to say.

Comment: Also, see some notes from Jimmy on this subject [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/12/12/dealing-with-duplication-in-mediatr-handlers/)

Comment: @TylerHundley, I must disagree with that. Let's assume that we have 100 queries like that. And I want to extend it, to add a logging when loading data. Now it will take me a lot more time to copy/paste code everywhere. Then it takes lot of time testing all queries. So to me, duplicate code makes it harder to extend, not beneficial at all.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe Fair points. I'd argue that cross cutting concerns such as logging should be handled via Mediatr itself through Behaviors when possible. I think reducing duplicate is overall a good goal, though its good to ask if the code is truly duplicate (they will always mirror each other entirely) or if it is simply the same for now (ie instead of using one DTO for input and output, use distinct DTOs for each as needs might change for one in the future). I think Jimmy gives some good thoughts in the article shared in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try below code. This way, you reuse the loading code, and at the same time, provide an end point to handle the request.

```
public class EntityFinder<TEntity, TDto> where TEntity : Entity
{ ... // Same as your code }

public class GetUserByIdQuery : IRequest<UserDto>
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public class Handler : IRequestHandler<GetUserByIdQuery, UserDto>, EntityFinder<User, UserDto>
    {
        public Handler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper) : base(unitOfWork, mapper)
        { }
        public async Task<UserDto> Handle(GetUserByIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await base.GetByIdAsync(request.UserId);
    }

}
```

Comment: How we can create base command handler. 

Actually, I want to enable/disable record. I don't want to duplicate my code